# Connecting to DSL Modem with Ethernet cable

Tags: internet, release-hera, ethernet

I am completely new to the Linux world, and have built my first computer. I have used Macs and Windows for many years, but decided to try Elementary OS. I don't have a huge technical background in IT.

I am trying to connect my computer to my **Xfinity router/modem** with an ethernet cable. My computer says it is connected, but every website fails to load. I have just upgraded to 5.1 Hera, and my system is a ***ASRock X399 Phantom 6 MB with a Risen 2950 threadripper CPU***.

If anyone can give me any guidance or suggestions, it would be greatly appreciated.

Joe

Answer (score 0):

Welcome in the elementary OS community.

For your **Xfinity router/modem**, I invite you to check if it is DHCP, you can do this in the control panel of your hardware.

If you need the user manual, I think this link will help you

https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/usermanuals

For your motherboard apparently you have this network card : **Phantom Gaming 2.5G LAN, Intel® Gigabit LAN**

For information, on elementary OS there is no change of the network icon when connected in ETHERNET, as on Windows.

---

After verifying that your router is in DHCP I invite you to do this on the command line

```
# check if your ethernet has an ip
$ ip add
```

if that's ok, try to see if you ping a website

```
$ ping elementaryos.stackexchange.com
```

for now I can only give you this as the beginning of answer

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try and let you know the results.